# How to do a for loop over a nested ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm going to make this 2D rendering engine as modular as I possibly can. I've come up with, but haven't yet finished, a priority list for drawing/updating sprites, so that I can control which sprites are in front of each other.

This code is meant to loop through each priority list and render every sprite in that list.

```
//I don't entirely understand what this for-each type of loop does.

public static void renderSprites(ArrayList<ArrayList<AbstractSprite>> priorities){
    for (ArrayList<AbstractSprite> priority : priorities){
        for(AbstractSprite sprite : priorities.get(priority)){

           renderSprite(/* what should I reference to get the relevant sprite? */);

           //this is my best guess at what the nested loop would be, but it obviously doesn't work.
          //any ideas?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for..each` construct iterates over every element in a collection or an array.  The construct is in the form:

```
for(Type varName : [Array || Collection]){
  //for each iteration varName is assigned an element in the collection/array
}
```

In your example the outer loop is properly constructed and will assign the `ArrayList` to the `priority` variable for each iteration.  The inner loop is not properly constructed since you want to iterate over each element in the `ArrayList` priority, however the code attempts to use an element from the `priority` `ArrayList`.  The following code shows the proper structure and replaces the `ArrayList` with the `List` interface, which is preferred over using the concrete type of the collection.

```
public static void renderSprites(List<List<AbstractSprite>> priorities){
    for (List<AbstractSprite> priority : priorities){
        for(AbstractSprite sprite : priority)){
           renderSprite(sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't consider List instead of ArrayList. Is there anything that you would normally want to use an ArrayList for instead?

Comment: @SamWalls I always use the `List` interface.  I am unaware of any methods that `ArrayList` exposes publicly that are not on part of the `List` interface.  This allows you to change your implementation if necessary without code changes.  So for instance, say you wanted to retain the order of a list and switched to a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList` all of the code that uses the `List` interface would still work without changes.

Answer (score 4):

Should simply be

```
for (ArrayList<AbstractSprite> priority : priorities){
    for(AbstractSprite sprite : priority){
        renderSprite(sprite);
    }
}
```

This assumes that the priorities arraylist is sorted in order from high to low priority, so you are rendering the sprites with the highest priority.

Remember that the `get()` method of an `ArrayList` expects an `int` which represents the index of the element you want to access. For-each loops are implemented to make indexing opaque to the user and simply iterate through the Collection instead.

Comment: Just wanted to add for the comment on sorting, those drawn first will be drawn over by those drawn later. So "highest" priority, if drawn first, will be overwritten by "lowest" priority if sorted from highest to lowest; which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Yeah I realised that, but I'll have to figure out a smart way of adding new priorities. Maybe by using what I want it be in front of/behind I can just shift the lower priorities forward one and put the new priority in that place.

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly there. You should have :

```
public static void renderSprites(List<List<AbstractSprite>> priorities){
    for (List<AbstractSprite> priority : priorities) { // You have priority here
        for (AbstractSprite sprite : priority) { // Now loop over priority to get sprite
           renderSprite(sprite);
         }
    }
}
```